# Laravel Creating userInfo database table when user registers

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am doing an extension build on the User model on larval 5.
What I want to accomplish is once the user registers and is validated I want **ANOTHER** database table created named userInfo which has a belongsto Relationship with the User model and the User model has a hasOne relationship with userInfo.

Two things. 
How to I successfully implement this logic. I was reading
http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models
and
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#registering-events-and-listeners

But Im not to sure

And second.
Where best do I implement this logic.

Thanks in advance

PS. I do not what to combine the two database because the user model is when they register and data that lives in userInfo is "optional" for the user to fill out After authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you want to create an additional related model to the user when they register. That should be pretty straightforward - something like:

```
$user->userInfo()->save(UserInfo::create([
    //whatever information you need to save to the userInfo table - if any
]));
```

as for where to put it, you have options there. You could put it the 'store' method on your registration controller.  Or extract it out to a service class 'RegisterUser', and create the user and userInfo there.

something like:

```
//controller method
public function store(Request $request, RegisterUser $registerUser)
{
    $user = $registerUser->handle($request);

    return view(....)
}

//RegisterUser class
public function __construct(UserInfo $userInfo)
{
    $this->userInfo = $userInfo;
}

public function handle($request)
{
    // create your user
    $user = .....

    $user->userInfo()->save($this->userInfo->create([
        .....
    ]));

    // whatever else you need to do - send email, etc

    return $user;
}
```

---

Edit:  If you are using Laravel 5 and the default registration scaffolding, then you can add code to the app\Services\Registar class.  This class is called by the postRegister method in the trait.  Change the create method:

```
// app\Services\Registar
public function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    $user->userInfo()->save($this->userInfo->create([
        .....
    ]));

    // whatever else you need to do - send email, etc

    return $user;
}
```

---

If you are using Laravel 5.1 then the Registar class doesn't exist anymore, the create method has been moved to the AuthController (the method is the same, just in a different location) so override it there.

Comment: I haven't touched initial scaffolding of the application so the store method is the `postRegister` function in `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers` trait. The examples you mentioned above makes logical sense but i can't seem to fit that into the `postRegister` function.

Comment: assuming you are using Laravel 5 (and not 5.1) you can actually add the code to the app\services\Registar class.  It has a create method that is called by the postRegister function in the trait.  I will edit my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer pointed me in the right direction but I made some simple tweek to your edited question.

```
$user->userInfo()->firstOrCreate([
'aboutMe' => 'Please Fill out so users can know about you',
'bodyType' => '--',
]);
return $user;
```