# How can I get the inserted user id and use it in my profile table in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to add another details for Users and what I did is I created an extra fields in my registration so it goes like this:

```
<h1>Other Details</h1>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control" name="phone"  placeholder="phone number" />
        @if ($errors->has('phone'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <textarea name="address" id="address" placeholder="your address" class="form-control"></textarea>
        @if ($errors->has('address'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Then in RegisterController I added those fields in the validation:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'lastname'  =>  'required|max:255',
            'firstname' =>  'required|max:255',
            'username'  =>  'required|max:16|unique:users',
            'email'     =>  'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password'  =>  'required|min:6|confirmed',

            'phone'     =>  'required',
            'address'   =>  'required'

        ]);
    }
```

Then in the validation part I have no issue but in saving to the table I don't know how can I get the inserted user id.

I created a migration for profile like this:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('user_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->text('address');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Then I also created a model for the User Profile

```
class UserProfile extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'user_profile';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then in my User model I added the relationship also:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'username',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function profile() {
         return $this->hasOne('App\UserProfile');
    }

}
```

Then my problem is in the saving of profile. Because in the RegisterController I only have this:

```
 protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name'      =>  title_case($data['lastname']) . ' ' . title_case($data['firstname']),
            'username'  =>  $data['username'],
            'email'     =>  $data['email'],
            'password'  =>  bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

How can I add my other details? I am still new in Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One user have one user_profile
You can refer to this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Try this approach:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'John Doe';
// rest of the user details
$user->save();

// You can get INSERTED USER_ID
$inserted_user_id = $user->id

// Or you can update user_profile
// without your INSERTED USER_ID very simple
$profile = new Profile();
$profile->address1 = 'Some address';
// rest of address details

$user->profile()->save($profile);
// this is working fine
```

Comment: You are welcome but if it can solve your problem, plz mark my answer is done

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$user = new User();        

$user->name = 'John';  

$user->save();

// Now Getting The Last inserted id

$insertedId = $user->id;

echo $insertedId ;
```

## Edit: Change this line:

return User::create(...)

to

$user = User::create(...)

and return

```
$user or $user->id;
```

But put a check to confirm whether the save succeed or not.

Comment: So should I remove the `return` in the creation of user data and move it in the saving of the profile?

Comment: Ok I'll try that approach. :)

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz, Seems you master laravel. I need yo help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41887504/how-to-solve-missing-argument-1-for-app-repositories-favoriterepositorydelete/41887543

Comment: @mosestoh: Not a master, just have some knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected function create(array $data)
{

 $user = User::create([
        'name'      =>  title_case($data['lastname']) . ' ' . title_case($data['firstname']),
        'username'  =>  $data['username'],
        'email'     =>  $data['email'],
        'password'  =>  bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);


 Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,  
        'phone' => '',
        'address' => '',
    ]);
return $user

}
```

OR you can use `$user->userInfo()`

```
$user->userInfo()->save(Profile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,  
        'phone' => '',
        'address' => '',
//whatever information you need to save to the userInfo table - if any
]));
```

[Laravel Creating userInfo database table when user registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32028388/laravel-creating-userinfo-database-table-when-user-registers)

Answer (score 1):

I think your code need to update like:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
 $userId = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(array(
   'name'      =>  title_case($data['lastname']) . ' ' . title_case($data['firstname']),
   'username'  =>  $data['username'],
   'email'     =>  $data['email'],
   'password'  =>  bcrypt($data['password']),


 ));

 echo $userId;

}
```

Hope this work for you!